# TypeError: songs.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm new to react Every time when i run the code it shows the same error. Can anyone explain what is wrong with this code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../Search.css'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class Search extends Component {

    state = {
        songs: [],
    };

componentDidMount(key) {
    axios.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=`+key).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({songs: res.data});
    });
}
render() {
    const {songs} = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">


                    <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="search" 
                    placeholder="Search..." 
                    id="search"
                    onChange={(event) => this.componentDidMount(event.target.value)}
                    />

                    <div>
                        {songs.map(song => (
                            <h1>{song.artistName}</h1>
                        ))}
                    </div>



        </div>


    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The error means `songs` is not an array. Probably I would check the data type of `res.data` what you get back from the API call if it is still an array.

Comment: I'm getting list of track in console, but i want to display it on screen

Answer (score 0):

The `map` method is available only for an `Array` type. This means that `res.data` is not an array. Please inspect the response coming from the request URL first.

Answer (score 0):

You should display the data only when it's available:

```js
render() {
    const {songs} = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
                    <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="search" 
                    placeholder="Search..." 
                    id="search"
                    onChange={(event) => this.componentDidMount(event.target.value)}
                    />
                    <div>
                        {songs && songs.map(song => (
                            <h1>{song.artistName}</h1>
                        ))}
                    </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```